Does R have an equivalent of disjunctive types?
I'm trying to set up a clean interface for a function foo that takes as one argument a list of (standard, named) probability distributions.
In a functional language, I could introduce a disjunctive type:
ProbDist = Normal mu sigma
         | Poisson lambda
         | Bernoulli p

I could then pass a list of values of type ProbDist into my function:
result = foo(prob_dists)

Is there any way of doing this in R? If not, is there a standard workaround? Everything I can come up with is ugly...
Edit:
As requested, my code. I am simulating both continuous + binary variables obeying the descriptive stats + correlations given in a paper. So simulate is similar to mvnnorm/rmvnorm, except that some output columns are binary. At the moment the code only supports Normal and Bernoulli random variables.
NB To keep the MWE short I have removed code to correct the correlation matrix for dichotomisation. (I.e. don't use it if you find this post on SO!)
MWE:
library(tidyverse)
library(mvtnorm)

# simulate variables according to descriptive stats & correlations
# Normals should have NA for cutoff, and 
# Binary variables should have NA for mean and sd 
simulate <- function(N, mean, sd, cor, cutoff) {
  
  # Take variable names from the correlation matrix if present
  var_names = 
    if (is.null(colnames(cor))) 
      sprintf("V%d", 1:ncol(cor)) 
    else
      colnames(cor)
  
  # Generate the covariance matrix to be used with mvrnorm
  # If a variable will be binary, use mean 0, sd 1
  #  otherwise use provided means & sds. 
  mvn_means = mean |> replace_na(0)
  mvn_sds = sd |> replace_na(1)
  covariance = outer(mvn_sds, mvn_sds) * cor
  
  # Generate the multivariate normal data
  mvn = rmvnorm(N, mean = mvn_means, sigma = covariance) |> 
    as_tibble() |> 
    set_names(var_names)
  
  # Compute thresholds for N(0, 1) from cutoff proportions
  thresholds = tibble(
    var = var_names,
    cutoff_Z = -qnorm(cutoff))
  
  # Apply cutoffs to the MVN data
  mvn |>
    # Pivot to long + add thresholds
    mutate(id = row_number()) |>
    pivot_longer(cols = -one_of('id'), names_to = 'var', values_to = 'Z_value') |>
    left_join(thresholds) |>
    # Apply cutoff
    mutate(value = ifelse(is.na(cutoff_Z), Z_value, as.logical(Z_value >= cutoff_Z))) |>
    # Pivot back
    dplyr::select(c('id', 'var', 'value')) |>
    pivot_wider(id_cols = id, names_from = var, values_from = value) |>
    dplyr::select(-c('id')) 
}


descs = structure(list(var = c("MEduc", "MSens", "Father", "Secure"), 
    binary = list(MEduc = FALSE, MSens = FALSE, Father = TRUE, 
        Secure = TRUE), mean = c(14.37, 0, NA, NA), sd = c(2.48, 
    0.75, NA, NA), cutoff = c(NA, NA, 0.703, 0.615)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

cors = structure(c(1, 0.51, 0.32, 0.13, 0.51, 1, 0.36, 0.18, 0.32, 0.36,
1, 0.12, 0.13, 0.18, 0.12, 1), dim = c(4L, 4L), dimnames = list(
    c("MEduc", "MSens", "Father", "Secure"), c("MEduc", "MSens",
    "Father", "Secure")))

sample = simulate(100000, descs$mean, descs$sd, cors, descs$cutoff)

sample_means = colMeans(sample)
sample_sds = sapply(sample, sd)
sample_cors = cor(sample) 


Interesting question. You might want to look at this blog post. It compares Rust enums (which are disjunctive types) to existing R functionality and prototypes an R enum using the new S7 OO class system. I'm not sure if that's the best solution for your case as I'm unclear what exactly you're doing in foo() that requires this. Are you looking for type safety, or to ensure mutually exclusive parameters? If you post your inelegant solution it may be easier to see if there's a cleaner approach.

@SamR Code as requested. It's not specifically type safety/etc., just that the interface with the disjunctive type is to me the natural/clean one. I am very new to R, though.  If you spot any code improvements whatsoever, please say!

No. And since there is no static type checking, manually implemented discriminated unions will lack most features that make them useful in other languages. :-(

@SamR I’m a bit confused by this blog post… it doesn’t really show anything that couldn’t be done easier and with less code using S3 instead of R7. And since it also doesn’t include any code that consumes these enums it isn’t even clear how they’re superior to regular string-based enumerations (as far as I can tell they are not: in both cases the client code still needs to manually check validity).

@KonradRudolph I found the absence of code consuming the enums to be mysterious and alluring - a promise of all sorts of potential uses. I agree though there's no obvious benefit to using the GridShape enum as the grid_shape argument in st_make_grid(). I do sometimes find myself emulating a Rust Result when writing code that might return an error from an external source but not raise an error in R, like an http request. Usually this is a kind of messy, ad-hoc list. It would be cool if this was a bit more explicit - maybe this is a way to do something like that.

Maybe that's emulating a Rust Option actually. I find these concepts quite hard to translate into R.

@Mohan What in that code that you would like to improve? Is it where you generate the covariance matrix?

@SamR it's the interface to simulate(N, mean, sd, cor, cutoff). Passing a bunch of NAs in mean, sd, cutoff is messy and it will only get worse if I add more distributions.

@Mohan does descs have to be a data frame? If it was a list of structures containing a vector of parameters with different classes you could make simulate() a generic and then dispatch the appropriate method for the parameters that are passed in.
